# R to LaTeX: Merge columns of dataframe at the end of a table (multicolumn) using kableExtra

Tags: r, formatting, latex, kableextra

I have a question concerning the transfer of tables in R to LaTeX. For a long time, I did the transfer manually, but in order to avoid mistakes and save time, I want to do automatically from within R.

So, I want to get the following sample table:

[image]

I tried the `kableExtra`-package with the following code:

```r
# libraries
library("kableExtra")
# init
tmp.data = c(
  "Desc1", "Innerdesc1", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  "Desc1", "Innerdesc2", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  "Desc2", "Innerdesc1", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  "Desc2", "Innerdesc2", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  "Other Text", NA, "Foo", NA, NA, "Bar", NA, NA
)
tmp = data.frame(matrix(tmp.data, nrow = 5, ncol = 8, byrow = T))
# save latex
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
tmp %>% kbl(
  caption = "Table Name",
  format = "latex",
  align = "llrrrrrr",
  row.names = F,
  col.names = linebreak(c("Level", "Type", rep(c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"), 2))),
  booktabs = T,
  escape = F,
  linesep = c("", "\\midrule")
) %>% collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "none")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I got the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Table Name}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{llrrrrrr}
\toprule
Level & Type & Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3 & Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3\\
\midrule
 & Innerdesc1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\multirow{-2}{*}{\raggedright\arraybackslash Desc1} & Innerdesc2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\midrule
 & Innerdesc1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\multirow{-2}{*}{\raggedright\arraybackslash Desc2} & Innerdesc2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\midrule
Other Text &  & Foo &  &  & Bar &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This code looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is not what I want in the first place. The last row should contain three merged columns. The LaTeX code should more look like this (using packages `booktabs`, `makecell`, `multirow`):

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Table Name}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{llrrrrrr}
\toprule
Level & Type & Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3 & Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3\\
\midrule
 & Innerdesc1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\multirow{-2}{*}{\raggedright\arraybackslash Desc1} & Innerdesc2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\midrule
 & Innerdesc1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\multirow{-2}{*}{\raggedright\arraybackslash Desc2} & Innerdesc2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\

\midrule
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell[l]{Other Veeeeeeeeeeerry\\Long Text}}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Foo}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Bar} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Maybe another package instead of `kableExtra` would be the solution? I also tried `flextable` but there seems to be no export to LaTeX. `xtable` does not seem to have the function of merging cells. Lastly, I took a look on `huxtable` but I could not get my head around it. I would appreciate a solution or a workaround in `kableExtra` as it seems very lightweighted.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can tell me what you struggled with in huxtable I might be able to help...

Comment: Well, I don't huxtable at all. Would be nice to see a sample code for my table :(

Comment: `as_hux(tmp) %>% set_caption("Table name")` is a start. Have you read the vignette?

Comment: @dash2 You mean this one? https://rdrr.io/cran/huxtable/f/vignettes/huxtable.Rmd
Kind of. It reads very difficult and has also no examples in the form of pictures. So, I doubt that this might help me in my specific case.